# how to prevent accepting invalid secure token acceptance by payflow pro transparent redirect

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

we have implemented paypal payflow's "Integrating the Secure Token Without the Hosted Checkout
Pages: Transparent Redirect". In this method it first creates securetoken and tokenid based on order total and shipping & billing address which in turns reuturns secure token and token id. Then paypal askes for credit card info with the secure token and token id and it makes the payment with the previously posted order amount. Now if someone replaces the securetoken and token id with some other secure token and token id of less amount, payapl accepts the payment. How to prevent this to happen ??
any help is appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="https://payflowlink.paypal.com">
<input type=hidden value="Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA=="
name=SECURETOKEN/>
<input type=hidden value="9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5"
name=SECURETOKENID/>
</form>
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. The tokens expire if they aren't used to complete a transaction. Do you have an example transaction ID that I can look up that shows this?

Comment: here i am asking is tht transparent redirect work in two steps. In first step I generate securetoken by hitting payment gateway processor (https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com). in response it sends back securetoken which is used in second step where it posted to https://payflowlink.paypal.com/ and paypal accepts the payment. now the problem here is that if someone using firebug or some developer tool replaces the securetoken value stored in html hidden input element. hope this will help you understand my problem. So we believe on live server some hacker is using this technique creating order.

Comment: I understand how they would do it but changing the secure token value and redirecting to the site would return an error unless the token was previously generated by your account, was never actually used in a transaction, and hasn't expired yet. 
Just changing the last digit in the token to be a 1 instead of a 5 shouldn't redirect you to a payment page. 
Do you have the secure token option enabled within your account?